# What is the most efficient way to use a large text file in a userscript?

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I have a text file with 15k pairs of key:value entries (string, average length 25chars), stored alphabetically based on key values. Like so:

```
key1:val1
key2:val2
...
```

I need to store it and access it from inside a userscript. What is the most efficient way to do so?

I thought of creating a simple JavaScript object storing those key:value entries inside the userscript. This is my current code:

```
var string = `the_text_file_contents`.split("\n"), obj = {};

string.forEach(function(pair){
    pair = pair.split(":");
    obj[pair[0]] = pair[1];
});
```

While the access would be fast (simple `object[key]`), the object would occupy a lot of memory. I could create an array instead, which I guess would require less memory, but with slower access (optimized with binary search).

I don't know enough JS, so is there another more efficient way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

If you want store variable you can use *[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)*.

```
if (!localStorage.firstLoad)
   localStorage.firstLoad = new Date();

console.log(localStorage.firstLoad); // You will get the same date
```

> The read-only localStorage property allows you to access a Storage object for the Document's origin; the stored data is saved across browser sessions. localStorage is similar to sessionStorage, except that while data stored in localStorage has no expiration time, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends — that is, when the page is closed.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

---

You have to parse the dico just one time, and copy/paste object constructor is more efficient.

```
const obj = {
  "ciel": "bue",
  "night": "dark",
  "pizza": "like"
};
console.log(obj);
```

```js
// STEP 1 : PARSE
const string = `ciel:bue\nnight:dark\npizza:like`.split("\n"),
  obj = {};

string.forEach(function(pair) {
  pair = pair.split(":");
  obj[pair[0]] = pair[1];
});

console.log(obj);

// STEP 2 : SAVE OBJ TO JSON & COPY/PAST ON YOUR FILE

document.getElementById("output2").value = "const obj = " + JSON.stringify(obj, "\n", 2) + ";";
```

```html
<textarea id="output2" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>
```